# How we create column in datagridview through vb.net loop

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

[image]

can any one Tell me how can i create columns in datagridview
so that 
when i select month number 1,3,5,7,8,10,12 (jan, march, may, july, august, oct, december) then 31 columns should be create in datagridview because these months have 31 days
when i select month number 4,6,9,11 (April, jun, september, november)then 30 columns should be create automatically in datagridview and
when i select month number 2 (feb) then then show 28 column in datagridview.
month will be selected from "Date time picker" 
This is employ attendance for created in vb.net I upload screen shoot for more explation.

Comment: Your question isn't really clear. Do you want to create a column, or do you want to show or hide a column? One is inserting and one is disabling the visible property of the column. In your photo columns are already created, but you might actually be talking about rows. Could you clarify?

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this on the DateTimePicker ValueChanged event:

```
DataGridView1.Columns.Clear()
For i As Integer = 1 To DateTime.DaysInMonth(DateTimePicker1.Value.Year, DateTimePicker1.Value.Month)
    DataGridView1.Columns.Add(i.ToString, i.ToString)
Next
```

`DaysInMonth` is a static function of the DateTime class that returns the number of days of the month and year you pass as parameters. This code just iterates from 1 to the value this function returns and adds one column for each day to the DataGridView.

Comment: can you Tell me i already save some textbox data in sql database on date (for example 1/12/2014) now can i show this data in gridview when i select data 1/12/2014 from datetimepicker then create all column and this data show in one column equel to date.